# Cookie problem with knockoutjs and ASP.NET MVC application on .NET 4.6.1

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, http, cookies

A few days ago, my test environment does not work as expected, because my cookie `LanguageIdCookie` which is updated when I change the language in my dropdown list, stopped working, and on change of any language it has default value 1.

Error in my console that I could see in Edge explorer:

> Cookies marked with SameSite=None must also be marked with Secure to allow setting them in a cross-site context. This behavior protects user data from being sent over an insecure connection.
> Resolve this issue by updating the attributes of the cookie:
> Specify SameSite=None and Secure if the cookie is intended to be set in cross-site contexts. Note that only cookies sent over HTTPS may use the Secure attribute.
> Specify SameSite=Strict or SameSite=Lax if the cookie should not be set by cross-site requests.

I would like to stress out that my website works perfectly fine in Firefox.

Application does not updating cookie value in Chrome and Edge.

I think everything is fine with my code/db (since it works ok in firefox), so can you please tell me what I need to do in my web.config file or to put something in the part in my code where I setup my cookie:

```
public int CurrentLanguageId
{
    get
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current != null &&
            HttpContext.Current.Request != null &&
            HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies != null)
        {
            HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["LanguageIdCookie"];
            if (cookie != null)
                return int.Parse(cookie.Value);
        }
            
       return 1;
    }
    set
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current != null &&
                    HttpContext.Current.Request != null &&
                    HttpContext.Current.Response != null &&
                    HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies != null)
        {
               
            HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["LanguageIdCookie"];
            if (cookie == null)
            {
                cookie = new HttpCookie("LanguageIdCookie");
            }

            cookie.Value = value.ToString();
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(10);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to put this in my web.config, but still I don't get updating the value to cookie:

```
<system.web>
    ...
    <httpCookies sameSite="Strict"/>
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, it seems that:

> Microsoft does not support .NET versions lower that 4.7.2 for writing
> the same-site cookie attribute.

...and the reasons listed are:

> We have not found a reliable way to:
>
> - Ensure the attribute is written correctly based on browser version.
> - Intercept and adjust authentication and session cookies on older
>   framework versions.

This information comes from the following MS Docs page:
[Work with SameSite cookies in ASP.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/samesite/system-web-samesite) under the heading ***.NET versions earlier than 4.7.2***.

You may be able to get the result you expect, with your current source code, across the various browsers **by using .NET 4.7.2 or higher**.

Comment: But browsers does not have .net frameworks inside of them. That's the concern of my server side, right? Im trying some mambo jambo here with the code, but unfortunately still nothing.

Comment: Correct --  .NET version concerns are all server-side concerns -- at least in your case.

Comment: so, why it works in Firefox, but not in chrome and edge explorer ? Is it due SameSite prop?

Comment: On this line `HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie)` after that, I can see that cookie not added (updated) in chrome

Comment: That line of code adds the cookie to the Response.  It is not yet at the moment of sending the response from Server to Browser.  When it does send the response from Server to Browser both Chrome and Edge are refusing to process the response -- so the cookie on the client-side (in the browser tools view) is NOT going to get update in that case.